# Html 5 pattern not work with multi lengths

Tags: regex, html

I tried to use html 5 pattern attribute with multi-length conditions but not work.

code:

```
<input type="text" name="blahblah"
   required="required" 
   pattern="\w{95}|\w{98}|\w{105}" 
   title="Invalid wallet address" 
   class="form-control form-control-md">
```

i want to allow only strings with lengths(95 or 98 or 105), above code show error when try to submit 105 string for example.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the character group `\W` (upper-case "w") which equals `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]` meaning it matches any non-word characters.

Use `\w` (lower-case "w") instead which equals `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` meaning it matches any word character.